# Nested IF Statement Returning False Instead of Result

Tags: excel-formula

I have a long nested IF statement that works with the year 2023 but if I drag the formula back and the year changes to 2022 I get a False instead of the result. If I take the last portion of the statement and put it in front of the first half and after the Forecast.ets formula the formula works for the year 2022 but not 2023. Really need help with this one, been struggling for a while now to get it to work correctly.

=IF(AND(YEAR(AX$3)=Graphs!$E$3,Graphs!$E$4="Steady"),FORECAST.ETS(AX$3,FLCAB1,Date,12,1),IF(AND(YEAR(AX$3)=Graphs!$F$3,Graphs!$F$4="Steady"),FORECAST.ETS(AX$3,FLCAB1,Date,12,1),IF(YEAR(AX$3)=Graphs!$E$3,(IF(Graphs!$E$4="-",(OFFSET(OFFSET(Projections!$A7,0,MATCH(DATE(YEAR(AX$3),MONTH(AX$3)-1,DAY(IF(DAY(AW$3)=28,(EOMONTH((MONTH(AX$3)-1),0)-3),IF(DAY(AW$3)=29,(EOMONTH((MONTH(AX$3)-1),0)-2),IF(DAY(AW$3)=30,(EOMONTH((MONTH(AX$3)-1),0)-1),IF(DAY(AW$3)=DAY(AX$3),(EOMONTH((MONTH(AX$3)-1),0)),IF(DAY(AW$3)=31,(EOMONTH((MONTH(AX$3)-1),0))))))))),Projections!$A$3:$AAA$3,0)-1),0,0,1,-1)),IF(Graphs!$E$4>0,(AVERAGE(OFFSET(OFFSET(Projections!$A7,0,MATCH(DATE(YEAR(AX$3),MONTH(AX$3)-1,DAY(IF(DAY(AW$3)=28,(EOMONTH((MONTH(AX$3)-1),0)-3),IF(DAY(AW$3)=29,(EOMONTH((MONTH(AX$3)-1),0)-2),IF(DAY(AW$3)=30,(EOMONTH((MONTH(AX$3)-1),0)-1),IF(DAY(AW$3)=DAY(AX$3),(EOMONTH((MONTH(AX$3)-1),0)),IF(DAY(AW$3)=31,(EOMONTH((MONTH(AX$3)-1),0))))))))),Projections!$A$3:$AAA$3,0)-1),0,0,1,-1))*(1+((Graphs!$E$4)/12))),IF(YEAR(AX$3)=Graphs!$F$3,(IF(Graphs!$F$4="-",(OFFSET(OFFSET(Projections!$A7,0,MATCH(DATE(YEAR(AX$3),MONTH(AX$3)-1,DAY(IF(DAY(AW$3)=28,(EOMONTH((MONTH(AX$3)-1),0)-3),IF(DAY(AW$3)=29,(EOMONTH((MONTH(AX$3)-1),0)-2),IF(DAY(AW$3)=30,(EOMONTH((MONTH(AX$3)-1),0)-1),IF(DAY(AW$3)=DAY(AX$3),(EOMONTH((MONTH(AX$3)-1),0)),IF(DAY(AW$3)=31,(EOMONTH((MONTH(AX$3)-1),0))))))))),Projections!$A$3:$AAA$3,0)-1),0,0,1,-1)),IF(Graphs!$F$4>0,(AVERAGE(OFFSET(OFFSET(Projections!$A7,0,MATCH(DATE(YEAR(AX$3),MONTH(AX$3)-1,DAY(IF(DAY(AW$3)=28,(EOMONTH((MONTH(AX$3)-1),0)-3),IF(DAY(AW$3)=29,(EOMONTH((MONTH(AX$3)-1),0)-2),IF(DAY(AW$3)=30,(EOMONTH((MONTH(AX$3)-1),0)-1),IF(DAY(AW$3)=DAY(AX$3),(EOMONTH((MONTH(AX$3)-1),0)),IF(DAY(AW$3)=31,(EOMONTH((MONTH(AX$3)-1),0))))))))),Projections!$A$3:$AAA$3,0)-1),0,0,1,-1))*(1+((Graphs!$F$4)/12))),""))))))))))

Comment: This is one of those times where we will need some test data and expected outcome with an explanation of what you are trying to do. No one is going to parse that monster to figure out what is wrong.  The best would be to use helper columns, breaking the formula into manageable parts to find where the error is.

Comment: In line with what @ScottCraner said.  Get the individual parts working, then make sure your nesting is working.

Comment: That's where I can seem to figure it out from. If I break this down into individual parts it works. If I add this into a much larger nest, which it was originally, every other part works except the last part, like here. The larger nest worked fine until I added the last if statement, which change any of the structure except a few more parentheses on the end.

Comment: to help with your nesting. replace the formulas that do stuff with  TEXT so you know where you are in the nest.  `IF(condition1,IF(Condition2,"TRUE 2","FALSE 2"),IF(Condition3,"True3","False3"))`.  If you think you have every TRUE/FALSE result for each IF covered, and you  get a result of "FALSE" instead of your custom text, then you provided an IF function where you only provided a TRUE result and did not cover what to do when FALSE.